# How to visualize mappings between object attributes

Tags: attributes, mapping, uml, visualization

I'm trying to visualize the mappings of attributes of several classes for my collegues (and my future me ^^ ).
We model classes in UML diagrams with a proprietary software. Because we have to map object attributes from two (not so well-designed) external interfaces to our objects, most team members have no idea which external attributes matching their counterparts.
It would be also useful for documentary reasons.

Any ideas how to handle this?

Edit: further explanation following

We transfer information from one business object to another. 
Our (simplified) setting: 
We have 3 systems (A, B - that's our system - and C). 
We get Data from A and C in a specific format (not the same for the two systems), have to copy their attributes to objects in our system, process the data and copy them to the other system. 
I try to visualize the mapping of the business objects (respectively their attributes) from the 3 systems to each other.

Simple example: 
System A offers us data represented by class Person. It has attributes id, name, givenname, street (which includes street name and street number). 
System B (our system) has also an Person class ... let's call it PersonItem. It has the attributes id, idExternalSystemA, idExternalSystemC, name, givenname, street, streetNumber. 
System C offers as a third Person class ... PersonElement. Its attributes: id, surname, forename, streetName, streetNumber.

Our application maps the attributes (using some logic) from A to B to C and reverse.

From A to B:

```
Field Person.id is connected to PersonItem.idExternalSystemA. 
Person.name is connected to PersonItem.name. 
Person.givenName is connected to PersonItem.givenname. 
Person.street is connected to PersonItem.street AND to PersonItem.streetNumber (we have to extract the relevant parts from the source or join them when copy to the other direction)
```

From B to C:

```
PersonItem.idExternalSystemC is connected to PersonElement.id 
PersonItem.name is connected to PersonElement.surname 
PersonItem.givenname is connected to PersonElement.forename 
PersonItem.street is connected to PersonElement.streetName 
PersonItem.streetNumber is connected to PersonElement.streetNumber
```

**Now I need a visualization that shows how we have to copy the attributes when transfered to the next system. 
A diagram with lines between the attributes would do so.**
I've read that it's not allowed to ask for tools directly but have to describe the problem. But probably I had ask for a suitable tool anyway ^^

Comment: What proprietary SW do you use?

Comment: Also, how does this mapping look like currently (by example)? Is it a business object you transfer?

Comment: The software is called Innovator (from a local company).

Comment: You better had written this in your question (use the edit label). I'll have to think this over (tomorrow since it's late here) and try to come up with an answer.

Comment: Thanks for advice, I've extended the question.

Comment: Our developer dealing issues concerning the proprietary UML software stated he can make this kind of modelling available in less than an hour (the tool is highly configurable but I have not enough skill for that), but earliest next week. That would be perfect so I don't have to re-create the classes in another tool (and we can generate the 1:1-mappings without manual work). If it works I will post a screenshot of the result for documentation reason. If not we will give Enterprise Architect a try.

Answer (score 1):

Using a non-standard attached link is one possibility which can be done quick an easy - but not UML compliant (see @RedBeards's answer).
This is how Enterprise Architect supports linking attributes:

[image]

To be UML compliant you can make use of qualifiers like this:

[image]

I used a `<<mapping>>` stereotyped association where role names represent the attributes to be mapped and the qualifier tells which attribute in the current class to map.

This is probably some overhead, but mapping in any case means you are working on a system that needs fixing. So the less mappings you see over time the better your system has got.

P.S. It seems that the graphical end point of connectors is not specified correctly in the UML specs. I have raised an [issue](http://issues.omg.org/issues/lists/unclassified#issue-42086) with OMG.

Comment: This <<mapping>> stereotype does not coming from UML 2.5 right? According to UML 2.5 specification (page 715), <<Trace>> defines "a relationship between model elements or sets of model elements that represent the same concept in different model "

Comment: @RedBeard Stereotypes can be invented at will. That's their intention. There are a couple of UML predefined stereotypes, though.

Comment: Of course, I created a lot of stereotypes but I do not want to reinvent the wheel if it is not needed... I am not aware about this <<mapping>> semantic because you created it. Association and <<Trace>> already have their own semantics. The latter seems to better fit with Cllaire intention

Comment: @RedBeard Well, it depends. Introducing the new stereotype is to identify a specific problem domain and I'd do so as far as I can overview it. Of course you can stay with trace or simple dependencies. There is no single solution.

Comment: Thanks Thomas for example and explanation. Maybe we're checking Enterprise Architect, if the solution our pro developer suggested won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to represent. If you are just trying to show how things are mapped between the two systems, I would model an Adapter pattern that shows how one API maps to the next.

Here's a great, simple example of a working Adapter pattern in Java.

[Adapter in Java: Before and after](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/adapter/java/1)

Answer (score 0):

For me, the best solution would be to trace (with a dependency or abstraction for example) this copy. For you can create your "links" inside a diagram  which is UML Compliant.

[image]

An alternative representation would be to use a matrix but this is more related to the tool functionalities...

[image]

Comment: I would have suggested a similar solution with Enterprise Architect which allows linking of connectors and attributes (which actually looks better than in your drawing ;-) However, it must be noted that neither your nor EA's notation is UML compliant.

Comment: Why is it not UML2 Compliant !? I used Abstraction Element stereotyped as <<Trace>>  coming from the Standard Profile (cf section 7.7.3 of UML2.5 specification). I do not know for EA's notation but this looks compliant... Of Course the matrix is only other representation you can stick on the diagram

Comment: Well, I mean the attachment of the links. Inside the frame does not feel right (not sure if it's mentioned explicitly that it must attach outside; will have a deeper look). The location of the link connection has no defined semantics and you are trying to define that. It's just this interpretation which is not compliant.

Comment: If you want to "trace" the Properties, the attachments of the links must be on the Properties i.e. inside the Classes. If you attach them outside this means that you attached the Classes and not the Properties. That's why the matrix looks more clear to me.

Comment: I just looked into the specs. I could not find a reference telling WHERE the connector should end. This is likely a flaw in the specs (or it's written somewhere hidden). But ALL examples attach links exactly at the border of elements. None intruding and none standing off. Maybe they thought this is obvious :-/

Comment: I have raised an issue with OMG: http://issues.omg.org/issues/lists/unclassified#issue-42086

Comment: I would not use the term connector which is UML metaclass we are talking about dependency, abstraction, relationship here... But once again my response is UML Compliant if you want to "link" two Properties the ends of the link should be on the border of the Properties not on the border of the Class. If the links end on the Class, it obviously links the Classes ...

Comment: Red Beard, this is the kind of visualization I also thought of.
I'm quite sure it's not UML compliant, but that doesn't matter as far as I'm concerned :)
Is the first picture you posted made with a software which enables mapping of class attributes (if yes: what's the name of it?) or a handmade one?

Comment: Claire, I am sure that this is a UML model. Concerning the representation I found it more clear if the ends are connected to the attributes and not the class. I used the open source  version of Modelio for this.

Comment: I've just tried the tool myself. Not perfect (lines have to be adjusted manually to look fine), but would do the job. I would use Element Realization as type of connection, because there's no text at the line. Thanks alot, Beard.

Comment: By using the tool you will find how to create fine  link from the start or hide some label...